# transfer ether from smart contract to my wallet : warning error encountered during contract execution out of gas

Tags: ether, wallets, transfer

Hi I awant to transfer transfer ether from smart to my wallet so I ceated a sendEther function in the smart contract

```
    function sendEther() public {
msg.sender.transfer(1 ether);
}
```

very basic function and when I try to call it from app.js

```
   App.contracts.MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
   return instance.sendEther();
 })
```

I got this

[image]

1. I don't understand why it's from the account to the smart contract
2. why msg.value is 0

Comment: Or you could be trying to extract ethereum from a smart contract that doesn't belong to you you thief

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand why it's from the account to the smart contract

MetaMask shows you the ETH you have to pay as gas costs.

> why msg.value is 0

Again, MetaMask shows you the ETH you send along with your transaction to the contract. Not what the final results of a transaction are.

Reasons why your transaction is reverting could be the smart contract doesn't have 1 ETH or you don't have enough ETH to pay for the transaction.